# Bidirectional belongsToMany association on same model

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, bidirectional-relation

This `EntitiesTable` has a belongsToMany association with itself:

```
class EntitiesTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);
        
        $this->belongsTo('Users');
        $this->hasMany('Information');
        $this->belongsToMany('LinkedEntities', array(
            'className' => 'Entities',
            'through' => 'Links',
            'foreignKey' => 'from_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'to_id'
        ));
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags');
    }
}
```

However, this association only works in one direction. When the table `links` only contains an entry `[from_id: 1, to_id: 2]`, `$this->Entities->findById(1)->contain('LinkedEntities')` correctly fetches the linked entity, but `$this->Entities->findById(2)->contain('LinkedEntities')` does not.

One solution would be to duplicate every entry in the table `links` and swap `from_id` and `to_id`, but this is not desirable. I much rather would like a belongsToMany association considering `from_id` as `foreignKey` and `to_id` as `targetForeignKey` and vice versa.

**How can a bidirectional belongsToMany self-association be implemented?**

## An Example

Consider the following graph-like network:

[image: graph]

Each dot has an `id` and maybe some additional information (like a title or coordinates) and is stored in the table `entities`.

Now the connections between the dots can be represented using a table `links`:

```
from_id     to_id
1           2
1           4
1           6
2           3
3           5
3           7
4           5
4           6
5           7
```

Note that each connection only is present once, 1-2 could just as well be stored as 2-1, the direction from-to does not matter.

Now, if I want to get all the nodes connected to node 1, I could use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM entities WHERE id IN (
    SELECT to_id FROM links WHERE from_id = 1
) OR id IN (
    SELECT from_id FROM links WHERE to_id = 1
)
```

See how easy that was? I just have to make sure to check both directions, as the connection is bi-directional.

I want this association mapped in CakePHP. I know this might very well be currently impossible, which is why I opened an [issue in the CakePHP github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7514).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20832098/2580794 The solution there only works for older versions of CakePHP, since the option `finderQuery` was removed.

Comment: Try to find Entities by $id, and add conditions to containable LinkedEntities WHERE is from_id = $id OR to_id = $id  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

Comment: Adding additional conditions will only limit the linked Entities further, since the resulting query would still require to_id to be $id.

Comment: I think you will need to create two associations: LinkedToEntities and LinkedFromEntities.

Comment: Maybe the foreignKeys are named a bit badly. There actually is no from and to in the association, from_id and to_id are meant to be interchangable. There is no logical reason for some linked entities to be in one or the other association except CakePHP does not seem to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$this->belongsToMany('LinkedEntities', [
    'className' => 'Entities',
    'through' => 'links',
    'conditions' => [
         'OR' => [
                'AND' =>['Links.from_id = LinkedEntities.id', 'Links.to_id = Entities.id'],
                'AND' => ['Links.to_id = LinkedEntities.id', 'Links.from_id = Entities.id']
            ],
    ],
]);
```

Place this inside the `EntitiesTable`